# Is this processus to pay a user, reliable and safe?

Tags: process, paypal, playframework, payment

I'm working on a project that require my application to pay the user to his paypal account when he asks it.

Here's how I did it so far:

1. The (logged) user goes to the Pay page that will list all his Payments (received or not)
2. He enters his Paypal email and his application (mine) password (for security)
3. The POST page get a list of all the Payments that have status="UNPAID" for that user and update the status to "WORKING" (to avoid the user to refresh the page before the whole process is done and resend the same amount of money)
4. We count the total amount to pay in that list (a simple `for`)
5. The amount is sent to Paypal via Paypal Adaptive Payment API (request: PAY)
6. The response is checked, if completed, the list status is set to "COMPLETED", if not, the list is reverted to "UNPAID" (the SQL update is made via a `WHERE id IN(x, y, z)` in case a second Payment request has been made during that time.
7. A message is then displayed to the user

But I need your help, I'm in front of one risky problem I'd like to avoid, and I would know how you would do:

- If the user hit refresh on the process page, I don't want to send him twice (or more) the amount (The "WORKING" lock is here for that, but what happens if the user hit refresh before I set the lock ?)
- Rare possible: what happens if the user hit f5 after the lock "WORKING" is made, but before the request to paypal, and a new payment is received. By following what I did, just one item (the new) would be get and set to WORKING, but all others previous payment would be losts

How would you do? What is the best way to make it to be 100% reliable?

Thanks for your help

**Note:**

The steps between 4 to 6 is made via a [PlayFramework jobs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/asynchronous#Continuations), called with `now()` and `awaiting()` the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can:

- prevent double [post via JQuery](http://greatwebguy.com/programming/dom/prevent-double-submit-with-jquery/)
- use the [checkAuthenticity()](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/security#csrf) method to validate the request
- do a GET redirect after processing the POST (so they can't submit the same 2 times even by mistake)
- do the payment processing asynchronous (see below)

For the payment, instead of calling the job, set the id's of payments in a queue (or table in the database) and a job that runs once per minute that processes that table if it has some data. When the user does the POST you redirect to a page that says that you are processing the payments and will notify if there is some issue. You can notify the user later via a UI warning using comet or via mail.

That way you don't link the request to the processing, and you won't have threading/racing issues, as well as being able to detect stale requests (payments already done) if you do a sequential processing.